# Types object base on arras of another object

Tags: typescript

i have a next code:

```
const arr = [
 {
   name: 'john',
   age: '20'
 },
 {
   name: 'anna',
   age: '30'
 }
]
```

Now i create a new object based at arr:

```
const obj = {} // {john:20,anna:30}
arr.forEach(o => obj[o.name]=o.age)
```

How can i dynamical type this obj, need interface like this:

```
interface IObj {
 john: number,
 anna: number
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can literaly infer all keys and values like here:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: '20'
  },
  {
    name: 'anna',
    age: '30'
  }
]

type Elem = {
  name: string;
  age: `${number}`
}

type Callback<Item> =
  (Item extends { name: infer Name, age: infer Age }
    ? (Name extends PropertyKey
      ? Record<Name, Age>
      : never)
    : never
  )

type Reduce<List extends ReadonlyArray<any>, Acc extends Record<string, `${number}`> = {}> =
  (List extends []
    ? Acc
    : (List extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
      ? Reduce<Tail, Acc & Callback<Head>>
      : never)
  )

const builder = <
  Name extends string,
  Age extends `${number}`,
  Item extends { name: Name, age: Age },
  List extends ReadonlyArray<Item>
>(list: [...List]) =>
  list.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem.name]: elem.age
  }), {} as Reduce<List>)

const result = builder([
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: '20'
  },
  {
    name: 'anna',
    age: '30'
  }
])

result.anna // 30
result.john // 20
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gWAFAxgbxzzzDgFsBTALhgHIArEACzFoBoji4BzaugJgAMtTgF8OuApxLk%20tOGFLtp8XjVoBmYWJwBdHDigBPAA4UYAUQA2FMqimTSlGtAQBLMNwDcnHnwAGACT4YACuZABGFAii-jiiBtjGZjAAwnBWVhFwwADWADwAklC2AHyonAAUxbYwFAAeJWAAJhAEME58HgBm0TAAcrJsql1gvcgAgrwwCZJ4APwwlYOUdY0ULW0ACgggZgjGANIURioLMABKFKAIzfkrFMNTFKVnMDRgFABu0QCUKh9vtFOP9sIZTOYrs1QsAKPkADJuaBrJqtS4UODNcBWIwTJBwIz5BRGUpPYDAFEbNFXG53VwebjDIIhcJRGL%20cpofCiTlVRHIhqotrofRzGCLCbkgFLfmwQVU4U9PoACQxzWGADotUrkAAVOBuKyi4jERZQmFw-WGskUgBkaQyWRyBVVmNKrzFeEBPwQoLwoJwoEgsAioUNzT6aHynAelM2MHpngkeGecbRzLCkWisWTMBqdnl8fwHVkNAewz8NFT4k4srTbSumOxuPxhPzHtKlSsSKgNHQWo1st0v1QHrw3egGoQFGhsMqlRywGGFBsZBHKHKlUIYoHi9zeHQK9sGs6uhoR7IGr8Yl%20w258AbM4tCJ7pQD2CDyOnEFCVlgaFDcNokqLBJG3E1OnURgWGUMVKwEbRJBrMCVEgugFCUfcRnULQRCQvR32-X8oCvRQ4BgAB6CiYC0HAiL-DVoLASjqKEHAgA)

I have used several extra generics, `Name`, `Age`, `Item` and `List` to infer each property. Think about it as about destructure. If you want to infer some nested prop in TypeScript, you should create for it generic.

**`Reduce`** - is an utility type. It recursively iterates over the argument, and folds each element. Just like you did in your implementation. Except, you used `forEach` whereas I have used `reduce`. It just a matter of preference.

If you think above version is  an overhead or overengineering, you can use this:

```js
type Elem = {
  name: string;
  age: `${number}`;
}

const builder = <

  List extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
>(list: List) =>
  list.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem.name]: elem.age
  }), {} as Record<string, `${number}`>)

const result = builder([
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: '20'
  },
  {
    name: 'anna',
    age: '30'
  }
])

result.anna // 30
result.john // 20
```